# get first img of website by url

Tags: jquery, url, image, favicon

I was wondering if there is a (Jquery) way of getting the first img on a website based on its url. For instance I have a list of results which are basically url's. I know there are services which provide thumbnails of websites but that is not what I'm looking for. So is there a way or service which gets the job done?

ps. I would like to show the favicon of the url if that is possible..

Comment: Where would this jQuery run? On a different site? Wouldn't that get you cross-site problems? Also, why would the favicon have any relation to the "first img on a website"?

Comment: @bzlm the Jquery would run on my site (obviously..) Getting the favicon is sort of 'second' question. So 'if img not possible than favicon'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if I should answer this as your question isn't very clear. I'm **assuming** that you're working on a web application using jQuery, and that this application has a list of URLs to web pages from which you'd like to load the favicon and the first occurrence of an image.

If this is indeed the case, I must disappoint you. Cross-domain ajax calls is a big no-no and most browsers won't let you do it. If you want to do what you're suggesting, **assuming** I got that right, you're going to have to involve a server side language such as PHP, Python or Ruby.

Do comment this if I got your question wrong.

Comment: Yes you understand the question, but if I understand you correct it is kind a prohibited. But why is this site: http://www.getfavicon.org/ doing it?? Are they doing something that is not allowed??

Comment: [getfavicon.org](http://getfavicon.org) isn't using Javascript to fetch the favicon, they are using what ever server side scripting language they prefer. You can easily make that sort of application using, for instance, PHP. It is however impossible to do it with pure Javascript.

Comment: @Youss, why don't you just use getfavicon.org instead? :)

Answer (score 2):

To get first image from a group of images, you would use `eq` like this:

```
$('.imgClass').eq(0).attr('href');
```

Or

```
$('.imgClass:eq(0)').attr('href');
```

To get first image of the page itself, you would use `:first`:

```
$('img:first').attr('href');
```

Comment: @Youss: No you are setting href and even wrongly. If you want to know how to set href you can ask another question and accept one here if it helped you step ahead.